# ¿Problema de Inicio de Sesión PHPMaker?

Tags: php, sql-server

Buen día, solicito de su ayuda comunidad.

Tengo un proyecto en PHPMaker que me han compartido para modificar, al momento de montarlo en un sistema Windows con AppServe (Es el servidor solicitado) y compilar el archivo pmp, realiza la compilación sin problema y ejecuto el localhost, pero al momento de iniciar sesión con las credenciales correctas me realiza una doble redirección, primero a index.php (inicio del sistema) y luego nuevamente al Login.

al momento de enviar el formulario, me manda al inicio y me redirige nuevamente al login (anexo imagen)

[image: Login redireccionado]

y me redirecciona, nuevamente al inicio de sesión:

[image: Inicio de sesión]

igual, aqui esta un .gif del error en ejecución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y provee un [repro] del problema en cuestión.

Comment: @padaleiana, he anexado mas detalles del problema, adicionalmente inserte in gif para que visualices el error, primero hace el login.php, luego a index.php y luego nuevamente a login.php (cabe destacar que he colocado las credenciales correctamente)

Comment: Por favor, lee el contenido del enlace proporcionado en el primer comentario. Puede deberse a varias causas, y si no se ve el código, no se puede tener pistas del motivo del error. Por cierto, recuerda que el código debe ir _como texto, con formato_, ya que [no todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).